# How to calculate percentage with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to calculate 2 percentage with Google Apps Script and insert the result inside Google Doc File, and then exported to PDF file.

But after script execution I get this inside PDF file : **NaN**

here is the calculation code :

```
var totalPrice= ui.prompt ('Price :');
var price1 = (totalPrice / 100) * 40;
var price2 = (totalPrice / 100) * 60;
```

here is the code where values are inserted in GDoc before PDF export :

```
body.replaceText ('##TOTAL_PRICE##', totalPrice.getResponseText ());
body.replaceText ('##PRICE1##', price1);
body.replaceText ('##PRICE2##', price2);
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution because I'm not sure about your whole script, when `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is put after the script of `body.replaceText` and before the script for creating the PDF file, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Now I thought that when `body.replaceText` is for Google Document, `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose()` might be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `totalPrice` value before.

It seems you're not converting prompt strings to number.

The best way for this it's to get values from the user. The code below check OK user response and a valid value.

```
function userAction() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var prompt = ui.prompt('Price :');
  var responseText = prompt.getResponseText();

  if (prompt.getSelectedButton() !== ui.Button.OK || !isNumeric(responseText)) {
    ui.alert('Nothing');
    return;
  }
  var totalPrice = +responseText;

  var price1 = (totalPrice / 100) * 40;
  var price2 = (totalPrice / 100) * 60;

  console.log(price2);
}

function isNumeric(str) {
  if (typeof str != 'string') return false;
  return !isNaN(str) && !isNaN(parseFloat(str));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks works fine with this code. I have just replaced this line **var ui = DocumentApp.getUi ();** because I'm using GDocs and not GSheets. thansk again ;-)